# Orchestrator R2 sharepoint 2013 OIP not showing the Title field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, system-center

I'm comparing two Orchestrator 2012 OIP's for SharePoint.  The one provided by Microsoft and the one that is posted on scorch.codeplex.org.  My question is about the Microsoft provided OIP.  What I'm seeing is that when I use any of the activities, the "Title" column is not displayed or available for use.  In contrast the scorch OIP does display the Title column as expected.  The scorch OIP is quite old and appears is not actively being maintained, where as the Microsoft OIP is being maintained.  If I could resolve why the Title column is not being displayed I think it will work nicely.  Thoughts\Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is something I've seen before. It may be a bug in the SharePoint 2013 IP, though it does work in some cases and not in others, so difficult to say what the cause is. My recommendation is to change your list to make the default Title column optional and hidden, and use a new custom field for the name of the item instead. See also:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118181/how-to-remove-title-column-in-sharepoint-2013-list